# Trigger the textarea message when clicking on href link

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, intercom

I am trying to customize intercom plugin on a wordpress website.
I need to trigger a message when clicking on a href link, (so simulate enter key on the textarea).

This is code used:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.start-chat-btn-advice', function () {
  var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  e.which = 13;  
  jQuery("textarea").trigger(e);            
});
```

Comment: You cannot insert a key into the event. Please explain what you really want to happen

Comment: To send a message I should enter my message to the textarea and press enter key, and what i need exactlly is to send a message when i click on a href link, to explain more, when user click on hrek link, a message will be added to textarea value and key enter triggered to the texarea to send the message, Thanks

Comment: Can't you directly execute/call that function which sends the message on clicking of this button instead of trying to trigger it on textarea?

Comment: Why not submit the form instead?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need

```
<form action="chat" id="form1">
  <div id="container">
    <textarea id="chatText"></text>
    <a href="#" class=".start-chat-btn-advice">Click</a>
  </div>
</form>

$(function() {
  $("#container").on("click",".start-chat-btn-advice",submitIt);
  $("#chatText").on("keydown",function(e) { 
    if (e.which==13) submitIt() 
  });
});
```